# (1054, "Unknown column 'click_data_id' in 'field list'") --django

Tags: python, django

when i clicked the `User_datas` on the admin site, the site told me `(1054, "Unknown column 'click_data_id' in 'field list'")`

Here's my models.py:

```
class Click_Data(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    click_times = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('word',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.word

class User_Data(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    click_data = models.ForeignKey(Click_Data)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('user',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user
```

when i run `./manage.py migrate -l` , the terminal show information below, something file's name in migrations directory.

```
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
registration
 [X] 0001_initial
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
yigu
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_gw
 [X] 0003_click_data_user_data
```

Could anyone give me some tips?

Comment: I think you better inherit and extend the existing django auth_user.

Comment: Was there an `username` field before in that model? Have you edited database structure by yourself?

Comment: @GwynBleidD these was an **username** field before in **user_data** model and i deleted it. But i didn't edit database structure. All the editions are done in the 'models.py'

Comment: Please show result of `./manage.py migrate -l` command

Comment: @GwynBleidD my friend`, i have changed the subject's name and added the result when i run './manage.py migrate -l' command, would you help me again?